# Prerequisites regarding creating package in Oracle Database SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, package

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6006.htm

On this page it is specified in the prerequisites that "Before a package can be created, the user SYS must run a SQL script commonly called DBMSSTDX.SQL."

Why we need to do so?
What happens on doing the so?

Comment: +1 for reading the documentation!

Comment: I don't think you need to run that file,  either sql plus or oracle xe is executing the file when the database is starting .

Comment: @DarshanLila: it's run once during installation of the database...

Answer (score 0):

The script `dbmsstdx.sql` creates the package `sys.dbms_standard`. It is called by the script `catalog.sql` which is normally run during creation of an Oracle database. I've never seen an database where it hasn't been run, it would also lack all the data dictionary views like `USER_TABLES` etc.